# Android: what are the best practices for up/back buttons?

Tags: android, navigation, back-button

I've been developing an android app. I'm a long-time android user and from my experience, I rarely (if never) use the up button provided at the top left of the activity and always use the back button and the bottom of the screen (either physical or on-screen).

I'm wondering if this is the case for most users? Is the back button sufficient or should I always provide an up button (iOS style) at the top left of the screen? Keep in mind that, in my app, the back and up buttons do essentially the same thing.

Comment: It's just what user wants and what developer providing. Yes, you don't need the `Toolbar` back button and no one uses all time. But I use my mobile in two handed (most times) in that case I feel `Toolbar` back button is quite convinent. Now from a developer perspective (or a design perspective) if you don't provide the back button in toolbar it's kinda look empty and plain. So yeah some users like to have back button and most developers like to place at top. But end of day both does same job. There is no best practice other than convenience.